# How to configure Rancher so that internal DNS resolves to custom address

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress, rancher, rancher-rke

I am new to Rancher 2.0 and I have a set of pods running in a 2 node cluster. Some of the pods need reach an internal DNS entry that will resolve to a port on some of the other pods with a custom address like `http://mypod:443` or `wss://mypod:443`. How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. `[...] DNS entry that will resolve to a port [...]` - do you want the dns to provide you with the port, is that correct?

Comment: Some of my pods need to reach out to other pods at a custom address that is internal to the cluster. Say pod A needs to reach pod B at ```http://mypodb:443```. I need to figure out how to configure a service or rancher coredns setting to achieve this.

Comment: Web application running in pod A is preconfigured to reach out to another web application running in pod B at ```http://mypodb:443```. Is there some kind of service that I can configure that will forward that request to the correct pod or target workload?

Comment: Do you mean sth like this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ ?